# Charter font with Xelatex

Tags: xetex, miktex, texlive

On my Mac with TexLive, I am able to use the Charter font by simply having

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charter}
```

On my PC (using Miktex), the same file complains that it is unable to find the charter font. I have check with Miktex's package manager and charter is indeed installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The charter package pre-installed in MikTeX is to be used with `\usepackage`: more at http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/. The package `XCharter` is also quite nice.

Comment: Actually, what about an MWE? :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is probably that since version 10.9, MacOSX has `Charter` as a `.ttc` font, and you can't have it on a Windows system. The `charter`package on CTAN only has type 1 version.

But you can use the `xcharter` package, an extension to charter with oldstyle proportional figures, small caps in all shapes/weights and superior figures. It has all the necessary stuff to use the fonts with (pdf)LaTeX, and an `opentype` version to use it with fontspec.

Alternatively, you can use the CharisSIL true type font. Here is a demo for both. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get small caps with these fonts, while they're obtainable with `pdfLaTeX` in the case of `XCharter`. Probably I missed something. As far as I know, Charis SIL doesn't have pdfLaTeX support.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{XCharter}
\newfontfamily\Charis{CharisSIL}

\begin{document}

 \textbf{With XCharter}:

\blindtext \\

\Charis

\textbf{With Charis SIL}:

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use XCharter like this, and have no trouble getting small caps: `\setmainfont{Xcharter}[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}]`.  (I also load `realscripts`, since XCharter has superiors.)  I have no trouble with small caps in CharisSIL either, though if you look quickly, you may miss them, since they’re slightly taller than the lowercase letters and not that much shorter than the already shortish uppercase letters.

Comment: @Thérèse: Doesn't work on my system. If I do as you say, I've an error message (no `begin{document]) and if I do it through `\addfontfeatures`, no error message, but  nothing  happens: smallcaps are indeed lowercase, and oldstyle numbers lining ones. This remains a mystery to me.

Comment: That’s odd.  Do you perhaps have an old version of the font installed somewhere, as well as the current version?

Comment: No. I have MiKTeX's version updated July 2014, and I also installed it as a system font.